# Count consecutive numbers in Excel and display all that are greater than 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of 1s and 0s in my excel.

[image]

I want the result to count all the consecutive ones and return only those that are greater than 1. So the result should be something like this:

11 (this is from 4 - 14 July)

4 (this is from 23 - 24 July)

And so forth. We ignore the 0s and the 1s that are not consecutive.  How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a lot easier than it looks.

Assume this sheet picture starts at A1, so “July 1” is in A2, and the “0” is in B2.

Then in C2 put either:

```
If( and( B2=1, B1=1), C1+1, “”)
```

Or:

```
If( and( B2=1, B1=1), C1+1, 0)
```

Depending on preference, and then copy it down.

This says “If this row’s number AND the previous row’s number are 1, then keep a running count in C.  If either this row or previous row’s are not 1, then reset this row’s C to be 0 or null so the count will start again at the next sequential 1s.”

Note that the FIRST 1 in a sequence of serial ones will still show 0, and that *may* not be what you intended.  If so, I’ll add a tiny bit of logic in my answer:

```
If( and( B2=1, OR( B1=1, B3=1) ), C1+1, 0)
```

“If this row is 1 and the previous OR NEXT row is 1 then this row IS part of a series of at least two consecutive ones, so increment the accumulator.”

Comment: He has already 0 and 1 in his list, he wants to sum it up somehow, I guess.

Comment: @Prema Correct, and the formulas I provided do that in the way he/she described.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked great!

Answer (score 1):

With help of Max's formula I can offer a complete solution with few helper columns.

Solution with dynamic arrays:

```
C2= =IF( AND( B2=1; OR( B1=1; B3=1) ); C1+1; 0)
D2= =IF(AND(C1>1;C3=0;C2>0);C2;"")
E2= =IF(C2=1;A2;IF(ISNUMBER(D2);A2;""))
H2= =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(E2:E28;(E2:E28<>"");"");SEQUENCE(COUNT($E$2:$E$28);;1;2));"")
I2= =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(E2:E28;(E2:E28<>"");"");SEQUENCE(COUNT($E$2:$E$28);;2;2));"")
J2= =IFERROR(MAX(FILTER($D$2:$D$28;($A$2:$A$28=I2)*($D$2:$D$28>1)));"")
```

Solution without dynamic arrays (Filter- and Sequence function):

```
G23=    =G22+2
H22=    =IFERROR(SMALL($E$2:$E$28;G22);"")
I22=    =IFERROR(SMALL($E$2:$E$28;G22+1);"")
J22=    =IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$28;MATCH(I22;$E$2:$E$28;0));"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's super organized and helpful. C2, D2, E2 worked fine except I had to replace all ";" to "," for some reason. But for H2, I2, J2, it doesn't work. The error says the function isn't valid.

Comment: @Mac_79 I updated my solution, so you can use it without dynamic arrays (Filter and Sequnce function). But with this you need one more helper column to generate uneven numbers.  In some Excel versions semicolon is used instead for komma. In yours you might need komma.